# How can replace my java selenium function to python selenium function

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the mentioned function, I want to change in python.

```
public void click(By element)
{
    dvr.findElement(element).click();
}
```

Comment: Also... why would you wrap a single line in a function? What purpose would that serve here?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert as given below,

```
def click(locator, value):
   if locator=="id":
     driver.find_element_by_id(value).click()
   elif locator=="name":
     driver.find_element_by_name(value).click()
   elif locator=="xpath":
     driver.find_element_by_xpath(value).click()
   ....
   ....
   ....
   else:
      put "locator is not matching with any option. please check."
```

Comment: Base.click("xpath = myconfig.buttin1")
TypeError: click() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You have to pass two arguments like click("xpath", "xapth expression")

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
def click():
    driver.find_element_by_whatever("whatever attribute").click()
```

For example:
If you want to click on a button with `id=btn`:

```
def click():
    driver.find_element_by_id("btn").click()
```

Read further [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct replacement as such. Reason being java ones use below kind of format

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("tarun")).click()
driver.findElement(By.Css("tarun")).click()
```

but same methods in python translate to

```
driver.find_element_by_id("tarun").click()
driver.find_element_by_css("tarun").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element('id', "tarun").click()
driver.find_element('css', "tarun").click()
```

So you don't get a direct translation. But you can do it like below

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
def click(element):
    by, value = element.split("=", 1)
    global driver 
    driver.find_element(by, value).click()
```

Then you can use the method like

```
click("id=tarun")
click("css=.tarun")
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I am facing below error now -                        
 Base.click("xpath = myconfig.buttin1")
TypeError: click() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: No spaces before and after `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
def my_function():
driver.find_element_by_id("submitBtn").click()
print("Button is clicked")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as well.

```
def click(self, identifer):
    driver.find_element(*identifer).click()

element = (By.NAME, "q")
click(element)
```